# laravel: when submitting form encoded in UTF-8 it is converted to java data type

Tags: forms, encoding, laravel, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using laravel 4.2. Im learning laravel and find myself caught up in one problem and I have tried in many forums and I haven't found the answer anyware. 
My problem is as follows:
I have this form embeded in a php view file:

```
     {{Form::open(['route'=> 'home.store'])}}
 <div class="container col-xs-5 ">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
            <!-- Split button -->
        <div class="btn-group">
         <select name="country" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" >
             <option disabled selected>Escoger Pa&iacute;s</option>
             <option>Argentina</option>
             <option>Bolivia</option>
             <option>Chile</option>
             <option>Colombia</option>
             <option>Costa Rica</option>
             <option>Cuba</option>
             <option>Ecuador</option>
             <option>El Salvador</option>
             <option>Guatemala</option>
             <option>Honduras</option>
             <option>M&#233;xico</option>
             <option>Nicaragua</option>
             <option>Panam&#225;</option>
             <option>Paraguay</option>
             <option>Per&#250;</option>
             <option>Puerto Rico</option>
             <option>Uruguay</option>
             <option>Puerto Rico</option>
             <option>Rep&#250;blica Dominicana</option>
             <option>Venezuela</option>
         </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Now, in home.store  I have:

```
$user-> country = Input::get('country');
```

This is meant to be stored in a database table with a field named "country" that is of type ENUM with the same options as the form. It works perfectly when I pick options without ansi character codes. However when I choose the option that contains a spanish tilde (´),that is set in ansi code, they cannot get stored in the database.

Now, to check what is getting as input I used in home.store :

```
return Input::all();
```

And it ouputs:

```
{"_token":"ofyHW7ElogegKJwMXQL3HsbugCSnRxbtkm0GVQ8y","country":"Per\u00fa"}
```

I can recognize the problem as: acsii code &#250 is translated to java \u00fa.
I have checked everywhere in the framework (FormBuilder.php and HtmlBuilder.php)to see if something is being defined as java in laravel but everything is set to UTF-8, so as the database, and so as the meta tag in the html view (the browser is set to utf-8 too)

I would greatly appreciate anyone help on this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `&#250;` (not `&#250`) is (among others) an XHTML and HTML escape representing Unicode code point U+00FA, LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE. (It's has nothing to do with any of the ASCII or ANSI encodings. None of the ASCII encodings have characters above 127, for starters.) The dump you showed is in JSON (not Java), and `\u00fa` is the correct way to represent U+00FA in JSON. I don't know why you say that's a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! it was enlightning. The thing was that all others values got uploaded correctly to the database except for when I selected values containing those XML escapes. These values are supposed to be uploaded to a database table in field with ENUM type property and UTF-8. The allowed enum types were stored as is (i.e. Perú). I tried various ways but couldn´t made it work. I will try to find a solution along the lines of your comment.

Comment: (I don't know laravel or PHP)